# Tunneling from the Internet to my Chromecast

Tags: tunnel, chromecast

Suppose I want to allow my friend to play, from her home, a Google Slides presentation on my TV screen which is connected to a Chromecast device.

However, Google Slides only allows her to cast her presentation to a streamer on her local network. So I thought of the following scheme:

Suppose I start a tunnel client like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) on my computer, which forwards incoming traffic from the public ngrok server to my local Chromecast. This takes care of my side of the connection (in theory, at least).

My friend then needs to run a local server that impersonates a Chromecast on her network so that every packet she sends to that server is forwarded to the public ngrok server and from there to my Chromecast.

Has anyone successfully done such a thing?